# How to fill table on jsp page with result from db?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have simple app that returns something from db, and I want to fill table on page with that response but it doesn't work.

```
Controller:
@RequestMapping(value = "/stocks/available", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getAvailableStocks(Model model) {
    List<Items> items = userStockService.getAvailableStocks();
    model.addAttribute("items", items);

    return "items";
  }

welcome.jsp
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
<tr>
    <td>${item.value}</td>
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td><a href="">Sell</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that welcome.jsp is used for view name "items"?